# CvMat setTo equivalent in javaCV

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have been trying to apply an Ellipse mask on top of a cvMat. In C++ the code would look like this :

```
Mat mask = Mat(warped.size(), CV_8UC1, Scalar(255));
double dw = DESIRED_FACE_WIDTH;
double dh = DESIRED_FACE_HEIGHT;
Point faceCenter = Point( cvRound(dw * 0.5),
cvRound(dh * 0.4) );
Size size = Size( cvRound(dw * 0.5), cvRound(dh * 0.8) );
ellipse(mask, faceCenter, size, 0, 0, 360, Scalar(0),CV_FILLED);
filtered.setTo(Scalar(128), mask);
```

Im unable to find any method in javaCV that is equivalent to setTo. 
Can anyone help with a work-around for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an optional mask with `cvCopy(CvArr src, CvArr dst, CvArr mask)`

The [watermarking example](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/OpenCV2_Cookbook_Examples_Chapter_2#Example%3a_Watermarking) shows some usage, not quite the same as what you are doing but might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a 1x1 Matrix from your scalar and use that instead
something like:

```
filtered.setTo(Mat(1,1,CV_16S1C1, 128), mask);
```

the method is defined as:

```
@ByRef
        public native opencv_core.Mat setTo(@ByVal opencv_core.Mat var1, @ByVal(
    nullValue = "cv::noArray()"
) opencv_core.Mat var2);
```